# Facebook SDK login in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, qualtrics

I have included Facebook login Javascript SDK to create a social login button and display participants' Facebook user picture in Qualtrics.

The problem I am facing now is that displaying the button and user picture works fine the very first time I want to show it, but not anymore on follow up pages (i.e. after clicking the next button). I've tried simply copying the code to the question on the pages where I want to show the user picture and button the second time, as well as adding it to the header in the look & feel section, but I cannot get it to work. It works fine on very the first page I use it in (regardless of where in the survey it is), but not for any follow-up pages. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

```html
<div id="status"></div>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      getInfo();
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into your app or we are unable to tell.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "<span style='color: #333333; font-size: 16px;'>Facebook account (please connect your account)</span>";
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '875253029346318',
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                          // the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
      version    : 'v3.1' // use graph api version 3.1
    });

    // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
    // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
    // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
    // the callback you provide.  They can be:
    //
    // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
    // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
    // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
    //    your app or not.
    //
    // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function getInfo() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', 'GET', {fields: 'first_name,last_name,name,id,picture.width(100).height(100)'}, function(response) {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "<span style='color: #333333; font-size: 16px;'>Facebook account (linked!)</span><img src='" + response.picture.data.url + "'>";
   });
  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->

<fb:login-button size="large" button-type="continue_with" scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with displaying the like button twice in one survey. It is because the survey does not load a new web on a new page, so it "thinks" that everything is already viewed. Therefore you need to force it to view it using [FB.XFBML.parse()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/).

Here is the example code for the like button which my colleague wrote for me. You can reimplement it for login.

```
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

if(typeof(FB) !== "undefined") {
    FB.XFBML.parse();
}
```

In case you allow your respondents to interrupt the survey and finish it later you need to use also this initialization before the code above.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.7' //some version needs to be here
    });
  };
```